# parity --warp taking forever

Tags: synchronization, parity, parity-wallet, warp-sync

I am trying to sync the parity wallet by running

`parity --warp`

Apparently this is only meant to take a couple of minutes, but this has been going on for a couple of hours.

[image]

Does any know how much time/space the warp sync to meant to take? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Your client is not warp-syncing. Could you try to increase `--snapshot-peers 16`?

Comment: Thanks it ignore warp and synced the entire chain already. Luckily Parity prunes the database, so should leave it around 10 GB

Comment: Warp sync can kick in anytime. Can you try restarting with `parity --snapshot-peers 16` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently went through this process. I think the documentation is a bit outdated in times of how long it should take (or the network is slower than the documentation assumes). There are about 4.2 million blocks. Given your setup, it looks like you are getting about 150 blocks / second. At this rate, it will take about 4,200,000 / 150 seconds ~= 8 hours.

Comment: No this math does not work. The first 2 million blocks are fast, the blocks at 2.3-2.7 million take probably a week, and after that it's getting faster again. And lately, blocks are very slow again since around block 3.4 million.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way of syncing Parity Ethereum client with the top of the chain is achieved using Warp sync in combination with `--warp-barrier`.

To make sure you get the most recent snapshot available and warp sync very close to the top of the chain, Parity Ethereum >=v1.10.1 supports the flag `--warp-barrier [NUM]`. Replace `[NUM]` with the chain's latest block number minus at least 10,000 blocks. Example: if latest block number is 5,633,123 you should launch parity `--warp-barrier 5620000`.

```
$ parity --warp-barrier 5620000
```

I recommend this parameter

```
$ parity --pruning fast --jsonrpc-interface all --jsonrpc-hosts all --warp-barrier 5620000
```

Ref: [How to get Parity Ethereum in sync quickly?](https://github.com/paritytech/wiki/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-get-parity-ethereum-in-sync-quickly)